# Modify global variable in while loop

Tags: bash

I have a script that process a folder, and count the files in the mean time.

```
i=1
find tmp -type f | while read x
do 
   i=$(($i + 1))
   echo $i
done
echo $i
```

However, `$i` is always `1`, how do I resolve this?

Comment: Also see: [A variable modified inside a while loop is not remembered on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16854280/2072269)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In your example the while-loop is executed in a subshell, so changes to the variable inside the while-loop won't affect the external variable. This is because you're using the loop with a pipe, which automatically causes it to run in a subshell.

Here is an alternative solution using a while loop:

```
i=1
while read x; do
   i=$(($i + 1))
   echo $i
done <<<$(find tmp -type f)
echo $i
```

And here is the same approach using a for-loop:

```
i=1
for x in $(find tmp -type f);
do 
   i=$(($i + 1))
   echo $i
done
echo $i
```

For more information see the following posts:

- [A variable modified inside a while loop is not remembered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered)
- [Bash Script: While-Loop Subshell Dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726764/bash-script-while-loop-subshell-dilemma)

Also look at the following chapter from the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide:

- [Chapter 23. Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

Comment: regarding the first solution, isn't it process substitution like so `< <(find ...)` instead of like so `<<<(find ...)` .... yours is the latter and that seems incorrect.

Comment: @AlexanderMills The `<<<` operator is called a [here-string](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html).

Comment: solution using for-loop doent work if the output contains spaces; but while-loops works

Comment: The "for" loop is the answer I've been looking for! :)

Comment: A simpler version of `<<<$(` is `< <(`. Using here documents causes problems. E.g. they ignore NULL bytes, like when the command `find … -print0` is used.

Comment: This answer solves the immediate issue of allowing `i` to survive past the end of the loop, but does not address the other issues still in the code.  Also, note that if the user wants the last value found by `find`, there are better ways to do this that would not break due to the presence of whitespaces in pathnames.

Answer (score 10):

```
i=1
while read x
do
   i=$(($i + 1))
   echo $i
done < <(find tmp -type f)
echo $i
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390497/bash-propagate-value-of-variable-to-outside-of-the-loop

Comment: This would solve the immediate issue of allowing the variable `i` to survive past the end of the loop, but the answer does not explain why this works. Also, correcting the many _other_ issues still present in the code would be trivial.