# Executing alias string command

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias

I wrote a simple script to go through my development project directory and add an alias shortcut for each one:

```bsh
shopt -s dotglob #Use shopt -u dotglob to exclude hidden directories
find ~/development/* -prune -type d | while IFS= read -r d; do 
    cur_dir="${d##*/}"
    cmd="alias ${cur_dir}=\"code $d\""
    echo "executing: $cmd"
    $cmd
done
```

And the output looks like this:

```
executing: alias project-1="code /home/my_user/development/project-1"
./alias_for_projects.sh: line 6: alias: /home/my_user/development/project-1": not found
...
```

If I copy and run the command:

```
alias project-1="code /home/my_user/development/project-1"
```

it just works... How do I fix my script?

Comment: @PauloTomé - your edit was incorrect!

Comment: Use an array to create the `cmd`, or better yet, just execute `alias "${cur_dir}"="code $d"` instead of running `$cmd`

Comment: @muru - if I just `alias "${cur_dir}"="code $d"` when I then try to run `project-1` it returns `project-1: command not found`

Comment: To make your new aliases work outside of the while-loop, see [Modify global variable in while loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402750/modify-global-variable-in-while-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. It's tricky to run [a command stored in a variable.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1) But you don't really need to store the command in a variable. You can just do `alias "${cur_dir}"="code $d"` where you run `$cmd`.
2. You're running `alias` in subshell. Bash runs piped commands in a subshell (unless `lastpipe` is set). But you don't need the pipe (or `find` either). You can just use regular globbing (which you're already using, so the `find` makes even less sense).

Combined:

```
shopt -s dotglob
for d in ~/development/*/; do         # trailing slash - only directories match
    cur_dir="${d%/}"                  # strip trailing slash
    cur_dir="${cur_dir##*/}"
    alias "${cur_dir}"="code $d"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading all comments, I fixed my script like this:

```bsh
shopt -s dotglob #Use shopt -u dotglob to exclude hidden directories
while IFS= read -r d; do 
    cur_dir="${d##*/}"
    #echo "${cur_dir}"="code $d"
    alias "${cur_dir}"="code $d"
done <<<$(find ~/development/* -prune -type d)
```