# Run a command after interrupting while loop with Ctrl-C in bash one-liner?

Tags: bash, sigint

In the below one-liner, I run an "infinite" while loop which prints some numbers:

```
$ bash -c 'trap stopit SIGINT; run=1; stopit() { run=0; }; while [ $run ]; do for i in {0..4}; do v=$(($i*50)); d=$(for ((k=0;k<=(5+$i);k++)); do echo -n $(($v*(($k+$i)%2))),; done); d=${d%?}; c=$(echo numbers $d); echo $c; sleep 0.1; done; done ; echo Done'
numbers 0,0,0,0,0,0
numbers 50,0,50,0,50,0,50
numbers 0,100,0,100,0,100,0,100
numbers 150,0,150,0,150,0,150,0,150
numbers 0,200,0,200,0,200,0,200,0,200
numbers 0,0,0,0,0,0
numbers 50,0,50,0,50,0,50
numbers 0,100,0,100,0,100,0,100
...
```

... and the "expanded" script is:

```bash
trap stopit SIGINT; 
run=1; 
stopit() { 
  run=0; 
}; 
while [ $run ]; do 
  for i in {0..4}; do 
    v=$(($i*50)); 
    d=$(for ((k=0;k<=(5+$i);k++)); do echo -n $(($v*(($k+$i)%2))),; done); 
    d=${d%?}; # cut final comma
    c=$(echo numbers $d); 
    echo $c; 
    sleep 0.1; 
  done; 
done ; 
echo Done
```

The idea is that the `while` loop runs "forever" and prints (running task), and once you get bored, you stop it by pressing Ctrl-C. However, what I want, is to print a message *after* Ctrl-C has interrupted the while loop - in the above example, that is the `echo Done` command.

In the above example, I hoped that Ctrl-C would set the `run` variable to 0, thereby making the loop exit "cleanly" which would then print the command and exit. Unfortunately, when I press Ctrl-C nothing happens, that is, loop keeps on going and then I have to explcitly `kill` it.

How can I make the above script/one-liner exit the while loop on Ctrl-C, and print the final message?

Comment: In `while [ $run ]`, without any tests inside the `[ ... ]` (only one argument other than the closing `]`), all you're checking is if the provided string is empty or not. Both `0` and `1` are not empty, so that test will _always_ be true.

Comment: Thanks, @muru - did not even think about quoting, great catch; but probably even quoting would not have helped, due to local scope of variables in bash functions. Turns out, best is just to have the trap handler print final message, and then just exit - posted my example below.

Comment: No, quoting wouldn't have helped. What _might_ have is comparing the value: `[ "$run" = 1 ]`, so: `bash -c 'trap stopit SIGINT; run=1; stopit() { run=0; }; while [ $run = 1 ]; do for i in {0..4}; do v=$(($i*50)); d=$(for ((k=0;k<=(5+$i);k++)); do echo -n $(($v*(($k+$i)%2))),; done); d=${d%?}; c=$(echo numbers $d); echo $c; sleep 0.1; done; done ; echo Done'`

Comment: Variables are locally scoped in functions only if you use `local` or `declare` without `-g`, IIRC, so that's probably unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it, I think:

```
$ bash -c 'trap stopit SIGINT; stopit() { echo Done; exit; }; while [ 1 ]; do for i in {0..4}; do v=$(($i*50)); d=$(for ((k=0;k<=(5+$i);k++)); do echo -n $(($v*(($k+$i)%2))),; done); d=${d%?}; c=$(echo numbers $d); echo $c; sleep 0.1; done; done ;'
numbers 0,0,0,0,0,0
numbers 50,0,50,0,50,0,50
numbers 0,100,0,100,0,100,0,100
numbers 150,0,150,0,150,0,150,0,150
numbers 0,200,0,200,0,200,0,200,0,200
numbers 0,0,0,0,0,0
numbers 50,0,50,0,50,0,50
numbers 0,100,0,100,0,100,0,100
numbers 150,0,150,0,150,0,150,0,150
numbers 0,200,0,200,0,200,0,200,0,200
numbers 0,0,0,0,0,0
Done
```

Basically, the concept with "changing a global variable to exit cleanly" will not work because variables in functions in `bash` are always local scope, and "shadow" the globals, see:

- [Modify global variable in while loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402750/modify-global-variable-in-while-loop)

So after reading

- https://phoenixnap.com/kb/bash-trap-command

... it turns out, its best to move the final command ("echo Done") in the trap handler, and after it, from the trap handler, issue `exit` directly (don't bother with the "exit the while loop cleanly to print afterwards" thing)